# MS Access available for Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-access

I can't find a straight and recent answer to this question on the internet.  I can see that there was no MS Access available for Mac as recently as 2012.  Is this still the case?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you try checking the Microsoft Store? https://www.microsoftstore.com/ Or Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access#Versions

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 your answer is as vague as what you get when you search. My conclusion is that there is NO MS Access available for Mac, but that there are alternatives to view the data. See also: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5357491?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @Ramhound  Well, not by default.  Can you point me to a webpage where it is obvious presented?  Thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/cat/All-Office/categoryID.69403900?icid=en_US_Store_UH_software_Office

Comment: @Ramhound checked the specs and indeed Office 2016 for mac has it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007   Already looked at MS Store.  Vague.  Wikipedia does not mention Mac, which is not the same as saying it's not supported.  Thanks.

Comment: Downvoters: Call this whining if you want to, but a downvote without an explanation is not going to prevent future occurrences of the thing you are downvoting.

Comment: @bob.sacamento - You asked a question you didn't research before asking.  I am only saying that because you indicated the most recent version of Office on MacOS was Office 2012 which isn't the case.

Comment: Close voters. It's not really that obvious - it's one of those things you almost have to know already before the marketing blurb starts to make sense. It's a real 'small-print' exclusion imnsho.

Comment: @Ramhound What I said was that the most recent and clear answer I could find to the question dated from 2012.

Comment: @LChip My vague "answer" is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @bob.sacamento "Already looked at MS Store. Vague"   Vague how?  It took me 2 seconds to get to the Office for Mac section that shows all versions of Office available for the Mac, and low and behold, none offer Access.  So I would say it's safe to deduce that MS doesn't currently sell a version of Access for the Mac.  :)  "which is not the same as saying it's not supported"  It's EXACLTY that. Do you expect them to list everything it's NOT supported on?  Access won't run on OSX, or Linux, or OS/2, or DOS, or CP/M, or..., or..., or...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access is PC only. It's never been available for Mac. The confusion arises because the packages advertised for "PC or Mac" include it - but it only runs on PC.

snip from the [MS UK page for Office](https://products.office.com/en-gb/buy/compare-microsoft-office-products?tab=tabs-2#)...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the description for [Office Home & Student 2016 for Mac](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Office-Home-Student-2016-for-Mac/productID.323023400?ICID=All_Office_ModF_HS16Mac):

> Fully installed versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and OneNote

The descriptions for [Office 365 Personal](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Office-365-Personal/productID.297833200?ICID=All_Office_ModF_365Personal) and [Office 365 Home](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Office-365-Home/productID.286395000?ICID=All_Office_ModF_365Hm) are the following:

> - Fully installed versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook, OneNote,
>   and more
> - **Also includes Publisher and Access for PC (not available for Mac).**

Additionally all of the products located under the For [home and students](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/cat/All-Office/categoryID.69403900?icid=en_US_Store_UH_software_Office) family include the same "suite includes" disclaimer:

> Application availability and features vary by platform, device and
> language. Publisher and Access are available on PC only.

There is only one conclusion based on the facts, Microsoft Access, is only available on Windows.